# Spring Security caching my authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've just added Spring Security in my Spring Boot project classpath. I did no Java Configuration or XML configuration.

The problem is that when I send a request to my resource **localhost:8080/users**, my first request gets authenticated **(via Basic Authentication)** normally, but the subsequent requests do not need any authentication header. Even if I restart my server, the requests are still being authenticated without entering any credentials.

I would like to turn this "cache" off.

I tried with lots of clients. Postman, SOAP-UI, browsers..Already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019029/spring-security-caching-basic-auth-not-verifying-subsequent-requests), but didn't works

Comment: If there *did* exist a cache, its lifecycle would extend only to the lifecycle of the application.  You sure you're not sending the header every single time?

Comment: @Makoto yes, im sure. Im not sending the header everytime

Comment: that is for JSESSIONID in cookies.

Answer (score 22):

You have to set session creation policy to STATELESS. Otherwise Spring security will use cookies.

(You can delete cookies in Postman in the cookies menu below the send button.)

Example configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(
                   SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue with my out-of-the-box Spring Actuator.

I had to add:  `.and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);`
to my `ActuatorSecurityConfig` Class.

```
package com.foo;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.EndpointRequest;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.context.ShutdownEndpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.PathRequest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;

@Configuration
public class ActuatorSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(ShutdownEndpoint.class))
                .denyAll()
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint())
                .hasRole("ACTUATOR_ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations())
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/foo/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those luckies who has configured security in spring xml this one also activates stateless security:

`<http create-session="stateless">...</http>`