# PostMan client Authorization parameters are not picked up by Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I am testing my Spring Security application using PostMan client. When I change the password and update the request and fire the request, I am not getting 401 error. Spring security does not call the UserDetailsService. Only when I change the username to some wrong username, the UserDetailsService is getting called and I start seeing expected results. This might be a security issue. Is there something I am missing here.

Comment: Sounds like either your credentials are not validated correctly or maybe you are not using the (correct) AuthentificationProvider. If also an exception is thrown you may need to add .exceptionHandling() to your HttpSecurity.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the error. Setting the sessionCreationPolicy to Stateless resolved the issue. This link talks about the issue - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50842258/spring-security-caching-my-authentication/50847571)